# Web page horizontally scrolling [page width issue]

Tags: css

I have buid a a test html page for one of the client , I am having issues with the width of the page, I just cant figure out what div is causing the width of the whole page to scroll
horizontly. Can anyone point out or provide any assistance. I want to stop the scrolling.
The link of the test page is [enter link description here](http://www.amaechiperformance.com/test-one.html)
Thanks

Comment: Your next button has a width of `590 px`.

Comment: [Validate your HTML.](http://validator.w3.org/) The "stray end tag div" errors are, I think, relevant.

Comment: @thirtydot . perfect it was div issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element:

```
<a title="Show next" id="next" href="#" style="display: block;" class="">
</a>
```

is 50% in width which comes from `layout.css`, line 63

```
#prev, #next {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.698);
 display: block;
 height: 509px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 130px;
 width: 50%;  <--- here
}
```

Comment: if i remove the width the arrow buttons will dissapear

Comment: I'm just pointing you to why the screen is scrolling (what you asked), not solving your page layout issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Your next button has a width of 50%. Which is calculated from its direct parent which happens to be the body tag. So it ends up being 50% of the browser window.

The shortcut solution is to set `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the:

```
right :-479px; from  #next
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving `width:50%;` to your id `#next` and `#prev` in combination. Give `width:auto;` separately to `#next`. It will solve your problem. :)